# List inflated from database, need to have one entry per user, it has multiples

Tags: android, arrays, list, sorting, collections

I have a list that i load from a database. This list contains all the users that contacted you and all the messages that they sent you. Now I need to take that list, and only show every user once, with the time of the last message received from that user. The list is a object list which contains the message, user id, user name and date of the message.

Now this was the logic I did to get the last date for each user. And then sorted them by the date using Collections:

```
ArrayList<NTFMessage> list = new ArrayList<NTFMessage>();
                if (ntfmsgsList.size() > 0) {
                    list.add(ntfmsgsList.get(0));
                    for (int i = 1; i < ntfmsgsList.size(); i++) {                         
                        for (NTFMessage ntfMessage : list) {
                            if (ntfMessage.getUser_from().contentEquals(ntfmsgsList.get(i).getUser_from())) {
                                LogService.log(TAG, "---------content equals doesnt add");
                                if (Long.valueOf(ntfMessage.getDate()) > Long.valueOf(ntfmsgsList.get(i).getDate())) {
                                    LogService.log(TAG, "---------content sets last date");
                                    ntfMessage.setDate(ntfmsgsList.get(i).getDate());
                                }
                                break;
                            } else if (!ntfMessage.getUser_from().contentEquals(ntfmsgsList.get(i).getUser_from())) {
                                LogService.log(TAG, "---------content doesnt equals does add");
                                add = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (add) {
                            LogService.log(TAG, "---------adds");
                            list.add(ntfmsgsList.get(i));
                            add = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                LogService.log(TAG, "---------List size: " + list.size());
                Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<NTFMessage>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(NTFMessage mess1, NTFMessage mess2) {

                        return Long.valueOf(mess2.getDate()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(mess1.getDate()));
                    }
                });
```

MY logic was: I create a new list, caled list. I add the first name in it, and then I go through the ntfmsgslist and add the names that are not in the list. If the name that i checked is already in the list then I will only change the date if it is bigger. Any ideea how I could do this to work?
Because right now it shows almost all duplicates, only one name is shown once instead of 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've complicated your code. You could simply do something like this:

- Use a `HashMap` where the key will be the user name and the value will be the actual `NTFMessage`(?)
- iterate over the entire ntfmsgsList list
- for each element in the list get the `NTFMessage` and extract the user name
- test it against the previous `HashMap` to see if you already have a key with this name. If you don't already have a key with this name then add it to the previous Hashmap along with its `NTFMessage`. If you do have a key for this name then use that `NTFMessage` and see where does its date stands(and based on that either replace the initial `NTFMessage` map object or update its date field).

Code example:

```
HashMap<String, NTFMessage> result = new HashMap<String, NTFMessage>();
for (int i = 0; i < ntfmsgsList.size(); i++) { 
     final NTFMessage current = ntfmsgsList.get(i);
     final String userName = current.getUser_from();
     final NTFMessage stored = result.get(userName); 
     if (stored == null) {
         // we don't have this username in the map so add it
         result.put(userName, current);
     } else {
         // there's already a message for this username so see what's up with that
         int status = Long.valueOf(current.getDate()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(stored.getDate()));
         if (status > 0) {
             // if status is greater than 0 that means the current item 
             // has a more current date or whatever logic you have
             result.put(userName, current);             
         }           
     } 
}
```

Comment: One quick question, after I do this, how do I turn the result hashmap back into an arraylist? I  tried doing a for iteration for the size of the hashmap and add the values, but then i found out that for "Get" i need the value not the index

Comment: @rosualin The map has a `values()` method if I'm not mistaken which returns a `Collection` which you could then add to an empty `ArrayList`.

Comment: thanks, but I already figured it out, did it, but I went to lunch after and forgot to post here. 10x a lot, I've never worked with hashmaps until now, and now I know how useful they are in some cases